# android problem with thread

Tags: android

I am working with a drawing application. ON A CANVAS i able to draw something as free hand.
What i am doing here, i just store the paths in a `List<path>`  and drawing on canvas synchronized by a thread.
when i am starting to draw for 1st time it is so smooth and speed also, but as paths are increased `List<Path>` size also increased so it becomes so slow , so terrible.
if i clear the List then again it becomes smoother.

But i want for every time it should be smoother.  How can i do it?

IS there any way?

Thank you

Comment: Are u using list for saving to use undo and redo functionality?..

Comment: yes i am giving undo & redo from that list

Comment: then you may use stack instead of list.. this is a link http://sites.google.com/site/tutorialsformobileprogramming/android-tutorials/android-files  which uses stacks for undo and redo if you can understand this program it will be useful for you and its not slowing down at all.... are you using surfaceView or anything else.. that will be considered too...!!

Comment: i got this before. I am using same thing stack only. But my question is why it becoming so slow?

Comment: Thats the concern that i have no idea because in my app its working fine...!!

Comment: can you show some lines of code where you think the problem is there...!!

Comment: On which touch event, you are drawing and storing the path on ACTION_UP event or on ACTION_MOVE?

Comment: Which example u gave me, i was working with the same thing . Even i am not getting where is the problem , bcz its working fine. but slow.

Comment: yeah there is a little problem in that code....if you will see craefully then the path will be drawn on Action_UP event where, it should be on Action_MOVE event.. Have you checked on that..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3881/discussion-between-mak-just4anything-and-jyosna)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using invalidate to refresh the screen on a View, only invalidate the area where you drew the new line. So the system will not keep drawing everything. Other option is you handle the event and you keep one list for your undo redo purposes and another smaller detailed list for actual drawing.